# Android : Using Showcaseview library

Tags: android, android-library

I'm new to android development and i am doing a project where i need to use this library : ShowCaseView library.
When i imported all the necessary libraries and run the project.This is the following error i'm facing:
"Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded"
and

### "Unable to execute dex: Java heap space Java heap space"

I followed the following tut's :
1)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244143/android-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space-java-heap-space?noredirect=1#comment35565432_23244143
 and changed my ecllipse -Xms and Xmx to 512 and 1024

can any one help....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still have this problem :)

To solve it remove the roboeltric lib from libs folder. That should do it!